# Deploying Nuxt with Docker, env variables not registering and unexpect API call?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, axios, nuxt.js

I am re-re-re-reading the docs on [environment variables](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env) and am a bit confused.

MWE repo: https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-nf

I made a plugin /plugins/axios.js which creates a custom axios instance:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const apiVersion = 'v0'
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/${apiVersion}/`
})

export default api
```

and accordingly added it to nuxt.config.js

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import session from 'express-session'
console.log(process.env.PUBLIC_API_URL)
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  env: {
    PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://localhost:6091'
  },
  //  ...
   plugins: [
   //...
   '@/plugins/axios.js'
  ]
}
```

I set `PUBLIC_API_URL` to `http://localhost:9061` in the `.env` file. Oddly, the log statement is correct (port `9061`) but when trying to reach the site there is an api call to port `6091` (the fallback)

## System setup

```
project/
|-- backend (flask api)
|-- frontend (npx create-nuxt-app frontend)
    |-- assets/
    |-- ...
    |-- plugins/
        |-- axios.js
    |-- restriced_pages
        |-- index.js (see other notes 3)
    |-- ...
    |-- nuxt.config.js
    |-- Dockerfile

|-- .env
|-- docker-compose.yml
```

### Docker

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt: # frontend
    image: frontend
    container_name: my_nuxt
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "npm run start"
    environment:
      - HOST
      - PUBLIC_API_URL

  flask: # backend
    image: backend
    container_name: my_flask
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile
    command: bash deploy.sh

    environment:
      - REDIS_URL
      - PYTHONPATH
    ports:
      - "9061:9061"
    expose:
      - '9061'
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    image: backend
    container_name: my_worker
    command: python3 manage.py runworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL
      - PYTHONPATH

  redis: # for workers
    container_name: my_redis
    image: redis:5.0.3-alpine
    expose:
        - '6379'
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15

ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}


COPY ./frontend ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
```

## Other notes:

1. The reason the site fails to load is because the new axios plugin (`@/plugins/axios.js`) makes a weird call xhr call when the page is loaded, triggered by `commons.app.js` line 464. I do not know why, this call is no where explicitly in my code.
2. I see this warning:

   > WARN  Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale past a single process.

I do not know what caused it or how to correct it

3. I have a "restricted" page:

```js
// Create express router
const router = express.Router()

// Transform req & res to have the same API as express
// So we can use res.status() & res.json()
const app = express()
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()
})

// Add POST - /api/login
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  if (req.body.username === username && req.body.password === password) {
    req.session.authUser = { username }
    return res.json({ username })
  }
  res.status(401).json({ message: 'Bad credentials' })
})

// Add POST - /api/logout
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  delete req.session.authUser
  res.json({ ok: true })
})

// Export the server middleware
export default {
  path: '/restricted_pages',
  handler: router

}
```

which is configured in `nuxt.config.js` as

```js
serverMiddleware: [
    // body-parser middleware
    bodyParser.json(),
    // session middleware
    session({
      secret: 'super-secret-key',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
    }),
    // Api middleware
    // We add /restricted_pages/login & /restricted_pages/logout routes
    '@/restricted_pages'
  ],
```

which uses the default `axios` module:

```js
//store/index.js
import axios from 'axios'
import api from '@/plugins/axios.js'

//...

const actions = {
   async login(...) {
        // ....
        await axios.post('/restricted_pages/login', { username, password })
        // ....
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: Do you have the environment variables set on the machine on which you're running the Docker container? You need to have HOST, PUBLIC_API_URL, REDIS_URL, and PYTHONPATH set on the machine since they are pass-through environment variables (they come from the machine's environment since they are not set in the docker-compose.yml file).

Comment: @furman87there is an `.env` file with these specified (sorry if that was not clear in the OP), the `console.log` statement from `nuxt.config.js` suggests that the env variable is picked up, but not carried to client

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you are working in SPA mode, you need your environment variables to be available during build time.

The `$ docker run` command is therefore already too late to define these variables, and that is what you are doing with your docker-compose's 'environment' key.

So what you need to do to make these variables available during buildtime is to define them in your Dockerfile with `ENV PUBLIC_API_URL http://localhost:9061`. However, if you want them to be defined by your docker-compose, you need to pass them as build args. I.e. in your docker-compose :

```
nuxt:
  build:
    # ...
    args:
      PUBLIC_API_URL: http://localhost:9061
```

and in your Dockerfile, you catch that arg and pass it to your build environment like so :

```
ARG PUBLIC_API_URL
ENV PUBLIC_API_URL ${PUBLIC_API_URL}
```

If you don't want to define the variable's value directly in your docker-compose, but rather use locally  (i.e. on the machine you're lauching the docker-compose command) defined environment variables (for instance with shell `$ export PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:9061`), you can reference it as you would in a subsequent shell command, so your docker-compose ends up like this :

```
nuxt:
  build:
    # ...
    args:
      PUBLIC_API_URL: ${PUBLIC_API_URL}
```

Comment: This solution is at built time, not at runtime, it should has a solution for runtime as when we pull docker image to use, it should be able to configure the environment at that time, not fix it at the build time.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - things only work if i supply the .env file along in the build process. But that apparently embeds the data from it in the image.. which is nonsense - who wants secrets embedded in the image...

Answer (score 3):

The Nuxt RuntimeConfig properties can be used instead of the `env` configuration:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config#publicruntimeconfig

`publicRuntimeConfig` is available as `$config` for client and server side and can contain runtime environment variables by configuring it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  ...
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    myEnv: process.env.MYENV || 'my-default-value',
  },
  ...
}
```

Use it in your components like so:

```js
// within <template>
{{ $config.myEnv }}

// within <script>
this.$config.myEnv
```

See also [this blog post](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/) for further information.

Comment: This solution does not solve the problem